# Is typename / class needed when declaring template

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

When declaring template params is `typename` / `class` necessary (as in language could not work with diff syntax I suggest below) . I know template params can be  integers so you would have to pick to default to int or to `typename` / class but still.

i.e. why not

```
template <T>
T max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

instead of

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

and

```
template<T, size_t n>
size_t array_size(const T (&)[n]) {
    return n;
}
```

instead of

```
template<typename T, size_t n>
size_t array_size(const T (&)[n]) {
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Like all other names, you have to tell C++ the "type" for that identifier.  `n` is a `size_t`, and `T` is a typename/class.  C tried this a while back, that variables with no type are automatically `int`, but it turned out to be a bad idea, and it's no longer allowed.

Comment: The `typename` or `class` is a requirement of an abstract type. The "typed" parameters (like your `size_t`) are called *expression* parameters, and their type is not abstract; it is supplied. Thus the lack of need for `typename` or `class` preambles.

Comment: I would ask : why even `template <T>`? Why not just `<T>`?

Comment: I disagree, although on not a very firm ground... my reasoning is when writing a template you should expect a typename to be default... like auto in pre c++11 days... no need to write auto xor register explicitly...

Comment: @Nawaz maybe parsing is problematic for <T>

Comment: why even `<T>`, why not templated by default (like polymorphic lambdas)? `auto max(a,b) { return a>b?a:b; }` (and an automagically deduced return type)

Answer (score 8):

The language could certainly still work if template parameters defaulted to being types; just as C used to work when variable types defaulted to `int` in the absence of a type specifier. There would be some ambiguities to overcome, for example:

```
typedef int T;
template <T> class C;  // type, or non-type value of type `T`?
```

However, forcing you to be explicit allows much better diagnostics. If I forget to specify the type of a non-type parameter, then the compiler can immediately spot the mistake and tell me about it. In your world, it would assume I intended a type parameter, and carry on trying to interpret the template accordingly; probably producing confusing errors, or perhaps even successfully compiling something that does completely the wrong thing.

I can't comment on whether that's the reason for not allowing a default here (or for removing default variable types from C, or for never allowing them in C++), but it's certainly a good enough reason for me.

Comment: +1. Great points. C++ template already produces full page error for a *minor typo*. Imagine how big and confusing errors would it produce if we were to write `<s>` . Is it a *really* type? Or I forgot to mention `int` along with `s`?

Comment: I would say good points, since I have trouble finding out where me not writing int n and just writing n would make problems without me being really dumb... :D Aka can you give legit case where mistake is only on the lib side(template) and user writes normal code that would compile great with correct template but doesnt compile , or even worse it compiles to wrong exe because of the lib bug)

Comment: Oh the answer is edited with even better example. +1000 for the typedef.

Comment: @Nawaz I hate typedef example... I mean ppl who use typedefs deserve all the painful diagnostic they get(also a bit more). :) I was looking for example where forgetting typename is problematic without typedef stuff...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: You should hate `<T>` for the same reason. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The template parameter type could be lots of different things. `typename` is the most common in practice, but you are required to specify it. I suppose the language could have assumed you meant `typename` if no type is specified, but they did not spec it that way.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, which specifically says "...is [this] necessary (as in language could not work with diff syntax I suggest below)" .

Comment: That's a hypothetical. SO is not for asking hypothetical questions like "what if C++ were designed in this other way."

Comment: @StilesCrisis: You're largely correct in that this question is borderline _not constructive_, but that does not change the fact that you didn't answer it.

Comment: (I say "borderline" because there are arguably concrete reasons to identify, and as Mike has shown there is a concrete answer as well. The "issue" is the _arguably_ bit.)